# How to get device's timezone with expo-localization?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, timezone

expo-localization's documentations says this about the Localization.timezone:

> Deprecated. Use Localization.getLocales() instead.

But the Localization.getLocales() returns a Locale object, which has the following attributes, none of which is timezone or anything that could help find it:
[image]

So how would I get a user's timezone with this package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually located in `getCalendars` method.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/localization/#localizationgetcalendars

```js
const { calendar, timeZone, uses24hourClock, firstWeekday } = getCalendars()[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try this one

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

It is alternatively return the same thing as you are expected

Comment: Yeah, tried this one already. Unfortunately, it is not compatible with React Native/Expo.